# Converting a 5 digit integer into a column

Tags: java

I have to write a program to convert a 5 digit integer such as 12345 or 00005 into a column showing each individual digit on separate lines. I am asked to use two different methods, a mathematical method and string method. While the string method has given me no problems at all I am having trouble pulling each digit out individually using a mathematical method. This is my code thus far.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //load scanner
public class digitseparator{
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a five-digit integer: ");
String name = in.nextLine();

double n = in.nextDouble();
double ffthdgt = Double.parseInt((double)n%10000);
double frthdgt = Double.parseInt((double)n%1000);
double thrddgt = Double.parseInt((double)n%100);
double scnddgt = Double.parseInt((double)n%10);
double frstdgt = Double.parseInt((double)n%1); 

System.out.println(frstdgt);
System.out.println(scnddgt);
System.out.println(thrddgt);
System.out.println(frthdgt);
System.out.println(ffthdgt);

System.out.println("String method Solution");
char frst = name.charAt(0);
System.out.println(frst);

char scnd = name.charAt(1);
System.out.println(scnd);

char thrd = name.charAt(2);
System.out.println(thrd);

char frth = name.charAt(3);
System.out.println(frth);

char ffth = name.charAt(4);
System.out.println(ffth); 
}
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  Any error messages?  Anything??

Comment: Received a hint of using modulus, for example 123 % 10 = 3, meaning there are three ones.  Then if you divide by 10 (using integers) you'll get 12 which removes the 3.

Comment: What did you think the `%` stuff above was sort of trying to do?  You just copied it from somewhere without understanding it first.

Comment: Good to see so much support on this community!

Answer (score 2):

First, `Double` has no `parseInt` method.  It has `parseDouble`, which is meant to parse a `String` into a `double`.  But you already have a `double`.

Next, you can extract a digit by...

1. Dividing by a power of 10 to eliminate digits to the right of the desired digit.
2. Taking the remainder of dividing by 10 to extract the last digit, with the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner; //load scanner
 public class digitseparator
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int arr[] = new int[5];
       System.out.println("Enter a five-digit integer: ");
       int d =in.nextInt();
       String name = Integer.toString(d);
       System.out.println(name);
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
      arr[i] = d%10;
      d = d/10; 
       }
       for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
       {
        System.out.println(arr[k]);
       }
       System.out.println("String method Solution");
       for(int m=0;m<5;m++)
       {
         System.out.println(name.charAt(m));
       }  
     }
   }
```

Hope this is what you want